# Can KNX Falcon SDK be used to communicate with KNX Virtual?

Tags: knx

I'm trying to create an application based on data generated by KNX devices on a smart home.
For this reason I have downloaded the [C# KNX Falcon SDK](https://support.knx.org/hc/en-us/articles/360004887279-Falcon-SDK-v5-7-2) and use it to communicate with [KNX Virtual](https://www.knx.org/knx-en/for-professionals/get-started/knx-virtual/index.php).
However, every time that I try to initiate a connection with KNX Virtual it crashes (the window closes).

This is the code that I use for creating a connection to the KNX Virtual:

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var options = new KnxIpTunnelingConnectorParameters(
                "127.0.0.1", 3671, true);

            using (var bus = new Bus(options)) {
                try {
                    bus.Connect();

                    Console.WriteLine(bus.IsConnected);
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

and here are the KNX Virtual settings:

```
IP address: 127.0.0.1
IP Port: 3671
KNXNet IP Router: 224.0.23.12
Interface TP: 1.1.255
```

My questions are:

1. Is KNX Virtual able to handle connections from Falcon SDK ?
2. If it is, am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in KNX Virtual which does not support the "NAT mode".

Change your configuation to

```
var options = new KnxIpTunnelingConnectorParameters("127.0.0.1", 3671, false);
```

to connect without "NAT mode".